# Most effective way to run execute API calls

Tags: jquery, python, mysql, api, scripting

I am 'kind of' new to programming and must have searched a large chunk of the web in connection with this question. I am sure the answer is somewhere out there but I am probably simply not using the right terminology to find it. Nevertheless, I did my best and I am totally stuck. I hope people here understand the feeling and won't mind helping.

I am currently working on a data driven web app that I am building together with an outsourced developer while also learning more about programming. I've got some rusty knowledge of it but I've been working in business-oriented non-technical roles for a few years now and the technical knowledge gathered some dust.

The said web app uses MySql database to store information. In this MySql database there is currently a table containing 200,000 variables (Company Names). I want to run those Company Names through a third-party json RESTful API to return some additional data regarding those Companies.

There are 2 questions here and I don't expect straight answers. Pointing me in the right learning direction would be sufficient:

**1. How would I go about taking those 200,000 variables and executing a script that would automatically make 200,000 calls to the API to obtain the data I am after. How do I then save this data to a json or csv file to import to MySql? I know how to make single API requests, using curl but making automated large volume requests like that is a mystery to me. I don't know whether I should create a json file out of it or somehow queue the requests, I am lost.**

**2. The API mentioned above is limited to 600 calls per 5 minutes perios, how do I introduce some sort of control system so that when the maximum volume of API calls is reached the script pauses and only returns to working when the specified amount of time goes by? What language is best to interact with the json RESTful API and to write the script described in question no1?**

Thank you for your help.

Kam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention what server side language you're using, but the concepts would be the same for all - make your query to get your 200K variables, loop through the result set, making the curl call to the API for each, store the results in an array, json encode the array at the end of the loop, and then dump the result to a file. As for the limit to requests per time period, most languages have some sort of pause function, in PHP it's sleep(). If all else fails, you could put a loop that does nothing (except take time) into each call to put a delay in the process.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Rob. I am currently building the web app using Flask framework so the server side operations would be written in Python.